# Filtrar registros con dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Buen dia compañeros estoy intentando filtrar los registros por medio de un dropdownlist pero al momento de dar clic al boton solo refresca la pagina pero no hace ninguna busqueda.

controlador

```
    public ViewResult Index(string estado, int? page)
        {

var estados = db.Representantes.OrderBy(p => p.EstadosT.Name).Select(p => p.EstadosT.Name).Distinct();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(estado))
                {
                   representante = db.Representantes.Where(s => s.EstadosT.Name.Contains(estado));

                }

                ViewBag.EstadosT = new SelectList( estados);
     return View(representante .ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
            }
```

vista

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{

Estados: @Html.DropDownList("EstadosT", "All")

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu DropDownList se llama `EstadosT` pero en tu action esperas un valor con el nombre de `estado`. Renombra tu control a `estado` para poder recibir los valores en el action:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
 Estados: @Html.DropDownList("estado", "All")
}
```

Recuerda que los nombres del control tienen que ser iguales a los nombres de los parametros del action para poder recibir el valor.